# How to create transparent circle in rectangle as Instagram does?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

Now I have a rectangle inside of which I resize and crop my image:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((scrollView?.bounds.size)!, true, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

    let offset = scrollView?.contentOffset
    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -(offset?.x)!, -offset!.y)
    scrollView!.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

For whole my controller please look at this [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SR4RVdmA)

So, my question is, how can I make like in Instagram, like this:

[image]

How to add black rectangle with the circle center and continue resize my image as I do it now?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/20064934/5362916

Comment: It is blend mode. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673209/how-can-i-colorize-a-black-white-uiimageview-programmatically/20673289#20673289

Answer (score 2):

**Use this code, this will works perfectly.**

```
    let radius : CGFloat = 50;//make it dynamic as per frame of your imageView
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) , cornerRadius: 0);//make it dynamic as per frame of your imageview
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius , 2.0*radius) , cornerRadius: radius)

    path.appendPath(circlePath);
    path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true;

    let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer();
    fillLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
    fillLayer.opacity = 0.4;
    self.imageView.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: my output for that code is as image]

Create one subclass of CALayer

with following code

```
import UIKit

class GradiantLayer: CALayer {
    func frameSetup() -> CGRect {
        let frameWidth:CGFloat = superlayer!.frame.width
        let frameHeight:CGFloat = superlayer!.frame.height
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight)
        return frame
    }

    override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContextRef) {

        let locations :[CGFloat] = [ 0.5, 0.5,1.0 ]
        let colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor,UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2).CGColor,UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2).CGColor]
        let colorspace : CGColorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()!

        let gradCenter: CGPoint = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.height / 2)

        let gradiant2: CGGradientRef = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorspace, colors as CFArrayRef, locations)!

        CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, gradiant2, gradCenter, 0, gradCenter, self.bounds.size.width, CGGradientDrawingOptions.DrawsAfterEndLocation)

    }

}
```

Now to add this outside circle use following method in viewDidLoad of viewcontroller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let gradiant:GradiantLayer = GradiantLayer()
    scrollView?.layer.addSublayer(gradiant)
    gradiant.frame = gradiant.frameSetup()
    gradiant.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to following answer, hopefully it works for you.
[Drawing a transparent circle on top of a UIImage - iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392903/drawing-a-transparent-circle-on-top-of-a-uiimage-iphone-sdk)

Actually main idea is to create square `UIView` with semi transparent background and drawing `UIView` with some radius and transparent background upon previously created square `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this easily with 2x `CALayer`.

Add a `CALayer` to your view that is the colour you want the outside mask to be. You may need to bring this layer to the front (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11015144/78496)

Then on that new CALayer, set its `mask` property to a `CAShapeLayer` with a completely white circle as its `path`.

You can see how to create the circular `CAShapeLayer` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28442517/78496